# Office 2016 and Office 2021 - product key registration issues

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, product-key, microsoft-account, software-activation

I have 3 legit product keys for Office 2016 and 1x for Office 2021.

All are successfully registered via Microsoft terrible key registration process. But when i access the links to try to see the list of registered Microsoft products it only shows one of the four product, and that product says there's a problem with the product key.

I have researched and there are numerous similar issues but not like this one.

Whats the best way to get this resolved? I do not have a very high opinion of MS customer support :(

**In summary;**

1. Genuine product keys
2. All 4 keys Successfully registered on MS account - confirmations provided verifying keys are legitimate
3. The "Your Products " page shows only 1 out of 4 products and that product says there a problem with the key

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

Comment: Check out this post, read all the threads in it too: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/604729/ms-office-professional-plus-2021-reinstall-after-s.html.

Comment: Thanks but your issue was not quite similar. I have registered separately purchased software with Microsoft, and the registration process did confirm the key. Within my Microsoft account it does not recognise that the product has been registered to my ownership.

Comment: Your problem is something only Microsoft can resolve.  However, I assume, you have the keys in some form that you can use to install Office?  In my experience of purchasing Office 2016, I was sent an email, with the installer associated with the key.  Note, it's trivial, to create your own Office installer through a configuration file you just have to provide the key and an installer.  **FYI The "pre-paid" key in the first screenshot is for Office 365 it's not a reference to the perpetual licenses.**

Comment: Your assumption/comment is not actually correct, but I understand why you think/assume that.

See my diagram above - the "Have a pre-paid key?" link takes the user to the 2nd image in my diagram titled "Let's get started" and within that page it has a product key entry, if you enter any valid Office Product there it validates and provides a confirmation of the valid (or invalid) key, and a download link to the product....

**See the 4th page of my Diagrams showing the confirmation and the download link**

Your comment is well-intended I'm sure but totally inaccurate!

Comment: @CaptainMacro - It’s not an assumption. Anyways there is a “change” url that should let you enter a different product key. Your Microsoft Account not listing your other product keys is something Microsoft should be able to help you with.  They through chat support have been able to provide product keys associated to my email (through the Home Use Program)

Comment: If under Subscriptions & Services, you can not find the licensed Office, you'd best to contact Microsoft. Besides, the product key is not displayed on the Subscriptions & Services now, I do not suggest you an account to bound with multiple same version of Office,  it is not clear which one is installed correctly on the corresponding machine.